# Adding a scrollbar to customized panel in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, panel, scrollview

Well, I'm trying to add a panel with a sort of map (a sort of image matrix) but the thing is that, since it won't have the same layout each time it gets created, I have no clue of how big will it be; therefore, I wanted to add scrollbars so the user could navigate through the panel yet I've tried different combinations and still I haven't found a successful one =(.

```
 LinearLayout platinumSeats = new LinearLayout(this);
        platinumSeats.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        platinumSeats.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        ScrollView seatChart = new ScrollView(this);
        TextView seatsLeft = new TextView(this);
        seatsLeft.setText("Available seats");
        seatsLeft.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        container = new Panel(this);

        seatChart.addView(container, 200, 300);
        seatChart.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        seatChart.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        platinumSeats.addView(seatChart);
        platinumSeats.addView(seatsLeft);        

        setContentView(platinumSeats);
```

I also tried adding the setXXXXXXScrollBarEnabled features in my Panel constructor but still no luck.
Any clues?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about adding your LinearLayout to a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)?  I see that you already have a ScrollView, but I notice that what is being added to it is 'container' is really never used anywhere.  You should be able to embed the entire LinearLayout into a ScrollView to get the desired effect.

This will allow your child view(s) to scroll when they are too large for the screen.  If they fit in the screen, you should notice no difference.

Comment: So then I should make a layout like Linear > Scroll > Linear > Panel? It's just that I need to add more elements into the main linear layout.

Comment: You may be able to remove the first Linear.  It really depends on what you are trying to do.  If you want to scroll the whole thing, then put the ScrollView at the top level.  If you want a certain section to scroll do as you suggested in your comment.

Comment: Well, I've put the panel into a linear and then that linear into the scrollview, but my panel is not displayed unless I set the measurement in my onMeasure method =S (but still, no scrollbar can be seen >_<).